# How to delete the URLSafeTimedSerializer token after use in python?

Tags: python, token, forgot-password, itsdangerous

I have created a token using python itsdangerous URLSafeTimedSerializer for forgot password functionality. The token is getting expired after the max-age but when the password is reset then i need to expire that token, so that the user is not able to reset password with the token again and again till it is getting expired. So, the question here is how to expire the token after the user resets password?

Comment: Hi please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question. Without the code that you already tried it is basically guessing and will not help you understand it. Post your code in such a way that it is quick to understand and without unnecessary code so we can point out what went wrong and help you out.

Answer (score 4):

So, say you generate a token via the `URLSafeTimedSerializer` library as follows:

```
from itsdanger import URLSafeTimedSerializer
ts = URLSafeTimedSerializer("my-secret-key")
token = ts.dumps(email, salt="my-salt")
```

In order to expire such token, you have different possibilities:

1. Create a blacklist of already used tokens (not a good idea as it would become too long and you may have clashes when generating tokens).
2. Add a 'token_reset' field to your user table, and store the current valid token there. As soon as the user uses it, delete it from the table. If no token exists for an user, it'll mean that he/she has already used it.
3. Add a timestamp to your token, so that when you get it back (you can decrypt it with the itsdanger library), you know if it has expired or not (though a user may use it twice in 5 minutes).

There may be other ways to solve such problem, but solution #2 is the one used most frequently (from my experience).